# Posting answers on different ubuntu versions

Tags: discussion, answer-format

Assume there was some problem for an older version of Ubuntu and some one have asked about that.Then I got the same or very similar problem on a newer Ubuntu version and I cold solve it by different way. If I need to post an answer about my way what is the best way to do it,create a new question and answer my self or post an answer on the old question that mentioning version?

Comment: If the difference is minimal, edit the existing answer (e.g.: https://askubuntu.com/posts/157621/revisions). If it's very different, post a new answer (e.g., https://askubuntu.com/a/998449/158442, https://askubuntu.com/a/516898/158442)